# Move vs CopyMemory in Delphi

Tags: delphi, pointers

Is there a difference between Move and CopyMemory in Delphi(specifically versions 2007 and up)?

If so, what are the differences?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have a look at windows.pas in Delphi:

```
procedure CopyMemory(Destination: Pointer; Source: Pointer; Length: DWORD);
begin
  Move(Source^, Destination^, Length);
end;
```

Does that answer your question? :>

Comment: How'd I miss the fact that one takes pointers and the other doesn't... Oh well, thanks a lot.

Comment: That, and the argument order is reversed.